# Как повешать событие jquery для списка на мобильном?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, на странице в мобильной версии есть селект

```html
<select class="m-cities-list">
 <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
  <option class="m-cities-option" data-link="<?=$arItem['PROPERTIES']['REG']['VALUE']?>" value="<?echo $arItem["NAME"]?>" ><span><?echo $arItem["NAME"];?></option>
 <?endforeach;?>
</select>
```

и на него нужно повешать событие по выбору

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.m-cities-option').on('click', function() {
            if ($('.m-cities-option').data('link') == "1") {
              window.location.href = "http://example.ru";
            }
            if ($('.m-cities-option').data('link') == "2") {
              window.location.href = "http://example2.ru";
            }
```

пробовал уже по разному, но так и не получилось сделать

Comment: Наверное не `click` надо, а `change`

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, у вас тег `span` не закрыт. Во-вторых, аброботчик надо вешать не на `option`, а на `select`. Наконец, событие не `click`, а `change`:

```js
$('.m-cities-list').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="m-cities-list">
  <option class="m-cities-option" data-link="1" value="1" ><span>1</span></option>
  <option class="m-cities-option" data-link="2" value="2" ><span>2</span></option>
  <option class="m-cities-option" data-link="3" value="3" ><span>3</span></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Все исправил, но при выборе на мобильном событие не срабатывает

Comment: Не могу повторить, у меня срабатывает.